# IIS Disable SSLv3 - Does it impact outgoing requests?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl, authorize.net, poodle-attack

I've seen descriptions [elsewhere](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-disable-ssl-2.0-in-iis-7.html) about modifying the registry to have IIS disable SSLv3. But, it isn't clear to me if this will impact both incoming requests to the server as well as outgoing requests. I have code connecting to Authorize.Net using HttpWebRequest. If I disable SSLv3 in the registry, will the HttpWebRequests to Authorize stop trying to use SSL and instead just use TLS? Or, do I need to change my code?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I think I figured this out. For anyone interested, disabling SSL3 in the registry did take care of requests to our server, but it did not impact the HttpWebRequests going out to Authorize.Net. I had to separately set the SecurityProtocol in .Net to make that work.